# How to not "return address of local variable" when modifying a copy of a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct, gcc-warning

I have the struct:

```c
struct mystruct {
        int a;
};
```

If I create a function with the struct as an argument,
and try to directly return its address:

```c
struct mystruct *
modifystruct1(struct mystruct s)
{
        s.a = 5;
        return &s;
}
```

Compiling with `c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` will warn `warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]`,
which [I know I shouldn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24184548).

However, if I save the address to another variable
and try to return that, the warning disappears:

```c
struct mystruct *
modifystruct2(struct mystruct s)
{
        struct mystruct *sptr = &s;
        sptr->a = 5;
        return sptr;
}
```

**Is this okay to do, or is it no different from the above?
(and if so, why is there no more warning?)**

**If not, how can I modify a copy of a struct inside a function
and return a pointer to that struct,
safely, preferably without using `malloc`?**

Comment: Yes. Have the caller provide the "copy" buffer as a second parameter in the function call and return nothing (or, perhaps some indication of success or failure.)

Comment: Just drop the pointer return and return the `struct mystruct modifystruct2(){ .... return s; }`

Comment: If passed a `struct`, why can't you return one (instead of a pointer)? `struct mystruct t = s; t.a = 5; return t;`

Comment: Following the Q edit, you are still returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: btw: copying large struct's on/off the stack is not efficient.

Comment: @Fe2O3 copying large structs is not efficient when they live on the heap either.

Comment: @n.m. The OP seems to want the caller to eventually have the original and a modified copy of the data. Whether those are "local variables" (to the caller) or on the heap is up to the caller. Passing/copying big chunks of data to/from functions is inefficient. I think we're saying much the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this okay to do, or is it no different from the above? (and if so,
> why is there no more warning?)

In fact it is the same. After exiting the function

```
struct mystruct *
modifystruct2(struct mystruct s)
{
        struct mystruct *sptr = &s;
        sptr->a = 5;
        return sptr;
}
```

the returned pointer will be invalid because it points to a local variable `s` with automatic storage duration that is not alive after exuting the function.

It seems the compiler is unable to determine that the returned pointer `sptr` points to a local object.

Pay attention to that the function parameter does not make sense because it is at once changed within the function.

If you want to change the object of the structure type passed to the function then pass it by reference through a pointer it it like

```
void modifystruct2(struct mystruct *s)
{
        s->a = 5;
}
```

If you want to create an object of the structure type within the function and to return it then define the function for example the following way

```
struct mystruct modifystruct2( void )
{
        struct mystruct s = { .a = 5 };
        return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass reference to the struct instead of struct itself (but it will modify the original struct)

```
struct mystruct *
modifystruct2(struct mystruct *s)
{
        s->a = 5;
        return s;
}
```

2. Dynamically allocate the new struct

```
struct mystruct *
modifystruct2(struct mystruct s)
{
        struct mystruct *sptr = malloc(sizeof(*sptr));

        if(sptr)
        {
            *sptr = s;
            sptr->a = 5;
        }
        return sptr;
}
```

or to do not pass the whole struct to the function

```
struct mystruct *
modifystruct2(struct mystruct *s)
{
        struct mystruct *sptr = malloc(sizeof(*sptr));
        if(sptr)
        {
            *sptr = *s;
            sptr->a = 5;
        }
        return sptr;
}
```

3. return struct by value

```
struct mystruct 
modifystruct2(struct mystruct s)
{
        s.a = 5;
        return s;
}
```

Comment: Would `static` storage duration be a viable option?

Comment: @Haris no, it makes function not reentrant

Answer (score 0):

at function call: modifystruct2(&s); (pass the struct adress)
I would use a typedefstruct.

```
void modifystruct2(struct mystruct *s)
{
        s->a = 5;
        return ;
}
```

Comment: What if does not want to modify the original structure?

Comment: @0___________ Then the OP should rename `modifystruct()` to `copyandmodifystruct()`.