# Using pointer returned by function gives special characters (in C)

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have a function that returns a pointer to a custom struct I made:

```
struct CustomStruct * function1() {
    // other stuff before this ... 
    struct CustomStruct cs = {param1, param2, param3};
    struct CustomStruct *cs_p = &cs;
    return cs_p;
```

then another function using the return value of this function:

```
void function2() {
    struct CustomStruct *new_cs_p = function1();
```

but if I try printing the values in `new_cs_p` I get weird characters. They print fine in function1 before I return them. Any idea as to what's causing this?

Comment: The solutions proposed in the possible duplicate are in C++. There is no `new` keyword in C. I tried malloc'ing the variable before calling the function which didn't help either.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at a different question, but [the linked one I'm seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475635/returning-pointer-to-a-local-structure) is in C, and it should answer your question. I'd also recommend reading [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap).